# MainActivity cannot run after splashcreen

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
package pi.com.pariwisata;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here. 
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_maps) {
            Intent peta = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(peta);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_list) {
            Intent list = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
            startActivity(list);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            Intent tentang = new Intent(this, TentangActivity.class);
            startActivity(tentang);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Keluar Dari Aplikasi?")
                    .setCancelable(false)//tidak bisa tekan tombol back
                    //jika pilih yess 
                    .setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //jika pilih no 
                    .setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and I have an error in `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please attach your manifest file

Comment: Looks like your MainActivity theme already having actionbar in styles, set your activity theme to noActionBar and then try this  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your Activity's parent theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

The important part is "**NoActionBar**"

Then you can use your custom **`ToolBar`** at your layout.

Comment: thaks for your suggest

Answer (score 0):

Set `windowNoTitle` and 'windowActionBar` in base theme of styles.xml and apply this theme to your application in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```